# Remove page numbers at bottom from PDF copy text

Tags: regex, sed

I copied some paragraph from a PDF file and want to remove page numbers at the bottom:

```
Duis diam dolor, iaculis a efficitur vitae, feugiat sed diam. Phasellus porta dolor non mauris
12
imperdiet ante. Etiam volutpat rhoncus massa, ut laoreet elit suscipit sed.
13
Integer quis ultrices turpis. Nunc molestie euismod aliquet.
14
```

If a line end with dot, its should be merged with next paragraph. I don't know how to combine these two paragraphs.

So final result should like:

```
Duis diam dolor, iaculis a efficitur vitae, feugiat sed diam. Phasellus porta dolor non mauris imperdiet ante. Etiam volutpat rhoncus massa, ut laoreet elit suscipit sed.
Integer quis ultrices turpis. Nunc molestie euismod aliquet.
```

I tried

```
[^.]\n([0-9]+)
```

on Linux bash, but no luck.

Comment: `sed` does not support PCRE. Are you really using `sed`?

Comment: I use just standard sed.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Is OP's regex outside the scope of `sed -r` or `-E` as well?

Comment: Is it GNU or FreeBSD sed?

Comment: The regexp is an ERE so in theory it'd wortk with a sed that has a `-E` option to support erEs (e.g. GNU sed or OSX/BSD sed) but then it'll still fail since sed reads one line at a time so it can never match a regexp that contains a newline (`\n`) unless you use GNU sed with `-z` to read the whole filee into memory at once oor come up with some arcane set of single character runes to populate a "hold" buffer first but if you do that then you're simply using the wrong tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;N;s/\n[0-9]+$//;ta;s/([^.])\n/\1 /;ba' file
```

Append lines, removing any lines with page numbers and any newlines if the previous line does not end with a period.

This will remove any page numbers, join lines inside a paragraph and leave previous paragraphs intact.

Answer (score 1):

This will produce the output you posted from the sample input you provided:

```
$ awk '!/^[0-9]+$/{buf=buf $0} /\.$/{print buf; buf=""}' file
Duis diam dolor, iaculis a efficitur vitae, feugiat sed diam. Phasellus porta dolor non maurisimperdiet ante. Etiam volutpat rhoncus massa, ut laoreet elit suscipit sed.
Integer quis ultrices turpis. Nunc molestie euismod aliquet.
```

It'll behave the same way using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box.